# how to add complex number to an array?

Tags: julia

First time looking at Julia

```
julia> x=[1 2 3];
julia> x[2]=3+5im

ERROR: InexactError()
 in convert at complex.jl:18
 in setindex! at array.jl:346
```

I am sure this is because julia typing system is different.

How would one do this below in Julia?

```
x=[1 2 3];
x(2)=3+5*1i

x =
   1.0000 + 0.0000i   3.0000 + 5.0000i   3.0000 + 0.0000i
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can make `x` a complex array:

```
x=[1 2 3];
x=complex(x);
```

Now you can perform this operation:

```
x[2]=3+5im;
```

This results in `x` containing:

```
println(x)
```

This outputs:

```
 1+0im 3+5im 3+0im
```

As desired.

Answer (score 9):

You probably want x to be complex. In which case, you can do this:

```
x = Complex{Float64}[1, 2, 3]
```

Which allows you to do what you want. You can also change Float64 to something else like Int or Int64.

Also, you should put commas after entries to get 1-dimensional arrays instead of 2-dimensional arrays, which is what yours are. To find the type do this

```
typeof(x)
```

which gives

```
1x3 Array{Complex{Float64},1}:
 1.0+0.0im  2.0+0.0im  3.0+0.0im
```

The 1 at the end indicates that this is a 1-dimensional array.